# Override method from Quoting module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I want override method **type_cast(value, column)** from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/ **active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/quoting.rb**

```
module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters # :nodoc:
    module Quoting

  # Cast a +value+ to a type that the database understands. For example,
  # SQLite does not understand dates, so this method will convert a Date
  # to a String.
  def type_cast(value, column)
    return value.id if value.respond_to?(:quoted_id)

    case value
    when String, ActiveSupport::Multibyte::Chars
      value = value.to_s
      return value unless column

      case column.type
      when :binary then value
      when :integer then value.to_i
      when :float then value.to_f
      else
        value
      end

    when true, false
      if column && column.type == :integer
        value ? 1 : 0
      else
        value ? 't' : 'f'
      end
      # BigDecimals need to be put in a non-normalized form and quoted.
    when nil        then nil
    when BigDecimal then value.to_s('F')
    when Numeric    then value
    when Date, Time then quoted_date(value)
    when Symbol     then value.to_s
    else
      to_type = column ? " to #{column.type}" : ""
      raise TypeError, "can't cast #{value.class}#{to_type}"
    end
  end
    end
  end
end
```

Problem in lines

```
when true, false
  if column && column.type == :integer
    value ? 1 : 0
  else
    value ? 't' : 'f'
```

I want get

```
when true, false
  value ? 1 : 0
```

In C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/ **active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb** class AbstractAdapter include Quoting.

```
module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters # :nodoc:
    extend ActiveSupport::Autoload

    ...

    class AbstractAdapter
      include Quoting

     ...
    end
  end
end
```

And class SQLite3Adapter inherit AbstractAdapter:
(C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/ **active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb**)

```
class SQLite3Adapter < AbstractAdapter
  def type_cast(value, column) # :nodoc:
    return value.to_f if BigDecimal === value
    return super unless String === value
    return super unless column && value

    value = super
    if column.type == :string && value.encoding == Encoding::ASCII_8BIT
      logger.error "Binary data inserted for `string` type on column `#{column.name}`" if logger
      value = value.encode Encoding::UTF_8
    end
    value
  end
end
```

How can I override method **type_cast(value, column)**? I try something like this

```
# config/initializers/sqlite3_adapter_extension.rb

module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters
    class SQLite3Adapter < AbstractAdapter

      def type_cast(value, column) # :nodoc:
        case value
        when true, false
          value ? 1 : 0
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But it predictable does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure from what you are doing exactly but if you want to do this for the specific modle you can override this method inside the model class itself but if you are sure that you want to override it for all your application you just need to create a new .rb file in your config/initializers and add the code like this

```
 module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters # :nodoc:
    module Quoting
      def type_cast(value, column) # :nodoc:
        case value
        when true, false
          value ? 1 : 0
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```